# Is it permitted to listen to instrumental secular music by an antisemite?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, music, anti-semitism

Assuming it is [permitted to listen to music composed or performed by a non-Jew](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5794/sources-for-listening-to-not-listening-to-non-jewish-music), is it prohibited, ill-advised, or outright permitted to listen to instrumental secular music by a composer who unabashedly hates Jews?

Relevant artists would include [Wagner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Wagner) and [Muslimgauze](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muslimgauze).

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1352/going-to-non-jewish-concert/3319#3319 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11938/being-exposed-to-christmas-music/11994#11994 Basically even if you are allowed to (I don't know), it's clear that you probably shouldn't. (Although I will admit to having listened to "Ride of the Valkyries".) If you search for "wagner israel" you will find that that it's enormously controversial, and essentially people refuse to listen to him.

Comment: I don't know whether it's permitted or not, but I would regard it as in the same spirit as collecting Hitler stamps or Hadrian coins, and definitely NOT promote the memory of an anti-Semite.

Comment: For a more recent example, I would include Roger Waters in this list. I have been quite ambivalent about Pink Floyd music since Waters began his vocal anti-Israel campaign a few years back.

Answer (score 1):

Though I don't have the original before me, the *Journal of Halacha and Contemporary Society ([Volume 14](http://download.yutorah.org/1987/1053/735711.pdf))*, cites the following<sup>1</sup> from Rabbi Hayim Dawidh Halewi (עשה לך רב כרך ג פרק ד):

> Secular music written by a wicked person, such as Wagner, is permitted as long as it does not endorse evil in the language (verbal or
>   programmatic) of the music itself.

---

<sup>1. This opinion pertains to **recorded music**. Without studying the original, I am uncertain if it pertains to live music.</sup>