# "I was waiting for my flight and a concert broke out."

Tags: mourning-aveilus, music, nine-days, three-weeks, simchah-joy-happiness

We've all heard that joke, right?

In all seriousness, though, a friend posted [this video](http://youtu.be/jf9C3Gmz-8U) of an impromptu concert at Toronto Pearson International Airport yesterday as all flights were either delayed or canceled due to the massive flooding throughout the city.

Of course, it's the Nine Days, when attending a live concert would be prohibited.  Is it permissible to remain and observe the concert?  Could one who hears about it by word of mouth, or who hears music coming from that direction, go to where it is taking place to observe it?

Sources, please.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2151/5

Comment: You must poke your ears out immediately!!!

Comment: @SethJ, is it a duplicate?

Comment: @msh210, that one is radio. This one is live. If you can stand in line while the radio is playing, that does not mean you can stay and listen to the concert. If you can't stay and listen to the concert, that does not mean you can't stand in line while the radio is playing. Only a 'no' answer to the radio question would have a potential Kal VaHomer implication for the concert question.

Comment: @SethJ, good point.

Comment: Are you specifically asking about the current case (Nine Days but before the Week of Tisha B'Av)?  If there's a distinction between halakha in this period and halakha during the Week of Tisha B'Av, do you care solely about the former?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, I'm just trying to keep it simple. If it can't be kept simple, I'll take an answer that explains the distinction.

Comment: This happened to me, sort of, and 2 days before Tisha B'Av so even in the week in which Tisha B'Av fell. I was on the start line ready to run the British 10K run and Katrina & The Waves decided to do a live performance. It was too loud to block my ears too.. Still I wasn't going to lose my place on the start-line.

Comment: See Ketubot 5a-5b. That’s why you have fingers that fit in your ears.