# Listening to music while studying/writing

Tags: halacha, music, sefirat-ha-omer, nine-days, three-weeks

Related: [Seth J's question here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2151/staying-to-enjoy-the-unexpected-playing-of-recorded-music-during-the-3-weeks-9-d)

Is it permissible to listen to music during sefira or the 3 weeks/9 days/week of 9 Av as a study- or writing aid? Many individuals I know (myself included) find music to be quite conducive to studying (secular materials) or writing papers. Would someone in that category be permitted to do this?

Comment: Listening to music to help one work out is permissible since it is not done for enjoyment,whether your case is the same I dk

Comment: Seems like Seth J's question answers your scenario. Personally, I can't study while music is playing as I tend to concentrate on the music and enjoy it and it distracts my studying. I'm inclined to think that most people are this way, as well. So, my own thinking is that, yes, it is problematic, based on what I have witnessed as mosty people's behavior. Unless someone is esp. disciplined NOT to at any time listen to the music, I wouldn't do it. You didn't ask about music while driving - may be same problem.

Comment: I can picture a lot of poskim's being lenient on this, based on the assumption that your studying is a part of your [future] livelihood